# Why doesn't HXT's xpath searcher return results for a simple query?

Tags: haskell, xpath, hxt

In http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath i tested that //i in  should work. Why doesn't it?

```
import Text.XML.HXT.Core
import Text.XML.HXT.XPath
import System.Environment
runX $ readString [] "<r><i/></r>" >>> getXPathTrees "/" >>> writeDocumentToString []
-- ["<r><i/></r>"]
runX $ readString [] "<r><i/></r>" >>> getXPathTrees "//i" >>> writeDocumentToString [] 
-- [""]
```

Comment: We really can't say if you don't provide the XML data.

Comment: It seems that the XML data is provided in readString's second argument — "<r><i/></r>".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The evaluation of the XPath expression is wrong.
For example, these queries

```
runX $ readString [] "<r><i/></r>" >>> getXPathTrees "/*[1]" >>> writeDocumentToString [] 
runX $ readString [] "<r><i/></r>" >>> getXPathTrees "/r" >>> writeDocumentToString []
```

should return the "r" element (the root element of the XML document), but return

```
["<i/>"]
```

It seems that getXPathTrees returns the content of the matched expression, so you have to return the parent of the node:

```
runX $ readString [] "<r><i/></r>" >>> getXPathTrees "/r/i/.." >>> writeDocumentToString []
["<i/>"]

runX $ readString [] "<r><i id='1'/><i id='2'/></r>" >>> getXPathTrees "//i/.." >>> writeDocumentToString []
["<i id=\"1\"/><i id=\"2\"/>"]
```

(I don't use HXT, and this is so wrong that I wonder if there may be another clean way to get the node without jumping to the parent…)

Answer (score 1):

Somehow, I think you are getting the text contents of the matched nodes.  I'm not quite sure why that is.  Here's what I'm seeing that leads me to that conclusion:

```
runX $ readString [] "<r><i>test</i></r>" >>> getXPathTrees "//i" >>> writeDocumentToString []
-- ["test"]
```

[The documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hxt-xpath-9.1.2.1/docs/Text-XML-HXT-XPath-Arrows.html) says: "XPath values other than XmlTrees (numbers, attributes, tagnames, ...) are convertet [sic] to text nodes." and I'm not sure how to write an XPath expression that returns an `XmlTrees` value, unless that that is used for a XPath node-set.  That doesn't seem to be the case, since an attribute is an XPath node, so it could be in a node-set, and the way the documentation is worded implies attributes can't be returned with that type.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is still searching for a way to get the contents of a text() node with HXT, the gist below shows another way to do it:

https://gist.github.com/jbpotonnier/1901205

Simplified from the above gist:

```
runX $ readDocument [] src
            >>>
            root [] [getXPathTrees "/some/path"]
            >>>
            writeDocument [] dst
```

Basically it wraps the text node in another node, before writing to a string.